# Ctrl-Super-Right doesn't work in 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, shortcut-keys, keyboard, shortcuts

Noticed today that the default Unity setting for keywords to partially maximize windows to left or right partially works in my laptop.

My Ubuntu is totally updated.

Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: *partially works in my laptop* What do you mean? When it stop to work?

Comment: I have this problem on Ubuntu 13.04.  Ctrl-Super-Right should put the window in the right half of the screen.  Ctrl-Super-Left works correctly, but Ctrl-Super-Right does not.

Answer (score 0):

Check your keyboard shortcuts are set right, and try manually remapping those commands.  All the unity keyboard shortcuts are customizable, under system settings > keyboard > shortcuts.

I'm not at my computer so I don't remember for sure if that's the location, but if not, just Google it's location.

If all that doesn't work still, you can reinstall unity with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Can't format my text, I'm on the mobile site
Hope that helps.