# Ctrl-Super-Right doesn't work in 14.04.1

Tags: shortcuts

I have the same problem as the OP [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256498/ctrl-super-right-doesnt-work-in-12-10), only my Ubuntu version is newer, 14.04.1. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> arrow combination works and moves the current window to the left half of the screen. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+ <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> also work. Only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> doesn't do anything.

How do I fix this? I tried reinstalling unity as suggested in the answer to the question I linked to but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check `system settings > keyboard > shortcuts`? If not try going there, search for this keyboard combination and make sure it's set right

Comment: I have. In the section 'Windows' I can only find ctrl + super + up or down but neither left or right... maybe it's in another section but I haven't found it.

Comment: @MinaMichael: Sorry I should've added your name so that you get a notification, did you read my comment? I still have no clue about how to solve the problem!

Comment: just saw it now. sorry I haven't been on askubuntu for a while. no clue. It's a very strange problem you're having

Comment: Same here, I tried reset the combination in ccsm, it was stored in ccsm but trying to grab from the keyboard it anew does not work. Grabbing ctrl+super+right on the other hand does work.

Comment: ctrl+super+up and ctrl+super+down are visible but not left or right in ubuntu 15.04. and unlike @Michalis for whom only the right does not work, for me neither right or left are working.

Answer (score 0):

I have partial workaround. Go to CompizConfig Settings Manager (you might need to install it first), disable and reenable Commands extension. This fixes some hotkeys not working like this.

For me it it fixed it only partially though. I can restore window only when it's not maximized. If it is I first hit `Ctrl+Super+Left` then `Ctrl+Super+Down`.